# registerSignatureHelpProvider not working in VSCode

Tags: plugins, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to write a plugin for visual studio code but no matter what, it doesn't call my provideSignatureHelp function I defined. I define it like this:

```
provideSignatureHelp(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position, token: vscode.CancellationToken): Thenable<vscode.SignatureHelp> {
    console.log("TEST");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("TEST2"); reject();
    });
}
```

And I also register it on startup using the `registerSignatureHelpProvider` function. However my provideSignatureHelp function is never called and nothing is ever printed. Everything else works fine but the SignatureHelpProvider is never called. I try typing my function and then a `(` and it doesn't show anything. Even after implicitly pressing ctrl-space there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok actually it was a very basic fix. Typescript didn't show an error when registering without any activation characters. So registering should also contain `"(", ","` at the end

Comment: Thank you!  Kind of annoying that in their documentation you configure the triggerCharacters in two different places.  I had it in the first place and thought that would cover it.
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#help-with-function-and-method-signatures